# PostCSS warnings when NODE_ENV=development

Tags: webpack, postcss

I'm working on a home-grown webpack config, and one of the pieces of it is PostCSS. Here are my PostCSS versions:

```
"postcss": "^7.0.35",
"postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.2.1",
"postcss-import": "^13.0.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"webpack": "^5.4.0",
```

My problem is that when NODE_ENV=development, I get this message spammed in the console when running the webpack-dev-server:

```
You did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.
```

I did set plugins, here is my postcss.config.js:

```
const postcssFlexbugsFixes = require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        postcssImport,
        postcssFlexbugsFixes,
        postcssPresetEnv({ stage: 3 })
    ]
};
```

And here is how I'm using it with the postcss-loader (yes, it's in a function because of how the config is designed):

```
const postCssConfig = require('../files/postcss.config');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const loaders = (isCssModule) => ([
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
    {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            importLoaders: 3,
            modules: isCssModule
        }
    },
    {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
            postcssOptions: postCssConfig
        }
    },
    'resolve-url-loader',
    'sass-loader'
]);
```

If I run the webpack-dev-server with everything exactly the same configuration except NODE_ENV=production, everything works. For the moment, I'm going to just disable PostCSS in development. However, this seems very strange. I'm not an expert with PostCSS, I'm wondering if it is a known issue or something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue? I having the exact same problem but with nuxtjs (which under the hood runs webpack as well). When NODE_ENV production the issue is gone and somehow it works fine.

Comment: I had the same error but the scenario was different. In my case I had 'postcss.config.js' file residing in some folder and it should have been located at the top level so the postcss-loader was not aware that any 'postcss.config.js' file existed and was giving after creating build.

Comment: The reason it only shows the warning in dev mode is that the error is only printed to console when `NODE_ENV` does not equal production: https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/e2f59d057f30d419e8fa7fac0095d3a47795714d/lib/processor.js#L26-L35

Comment: In my case, the problem was that PostCSS was actually not finding the PostCSS config file. I needed to specify it manually via the `config` option.